# Compressing ZIP files in a linux server with PHP

Tags: php, linux, zip, compression

I am trying to create a .zip file of a folder in linux.

First I go where the compressed folder is:

```
shell_exec('cd /var/www/vhosts/website/test/');
```

The folder test has the folder testzip which should be zipped and sent somewhere else:

```
shell_exec('zip a -r -tzip /var/www/vhosts/website/zip/save/testzip.zip /var/www/vhosts/website/test/testzip');
```

This should create `testzip.zip`. Somehow this doesn't work.

Could anyone help?

Comment: Have you checked zip command is installed in linux ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
"zip -a -r ..."
```

instead of

```
"zip a -r ..."
```

**--- EDIT ---**

Reading the comment of Mark Adler, I realized that you're using `zip` with  7-zip parameters.

So... are you sure that your `zip` is a link to `7z`?

Anyhow, I suggest you to avoid ambiguities: is your intention is use `7z`, explicit it with

```
"7z a -r -tzip ..."
```

If you want call the `zip` executable, use a correct `zip` syntax.

p.s.: sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 1):

Those are not options for zip. What are you trying to ask for with `-tzip`? The `a` at the start would create an `a.zip`. If you meant `-a`, there is no `-a` option for zip. The only option that makes sense is the `-r`, to recurse into subdirectories.

First run the command directly in the shell and resolve the errors you get, before trying to use `shell_exec()`.